# Why doesn't the percentage width child in absolutely positioned parent work in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, internet-explorer-7

I have an absolutely positioned div containing several children, one of which is a relatively positioned div. When I use a percentage-based width on the child div, it collapses to 0 width on IE7, but not on Firefox or Safari.

If I use pixel width, it works. If the parent is relatively positioned, the percentage width on the child works.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Is there an area of the CSS specification that covers this?

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: Does the absolutely positioned div have an explicit width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE7 has many bugs, including [computed dimensions](http://brunildo.org/test/abs_h100.html), [percentage calculations](http://positioniseverything.net/explorer/percentages.html), and [containing block binding](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html#cb). Using `zoom:1` or `display:inline-block` on the parent element is probably the fix in this case.